# Cannot open TensorBoard in Google Cloud JupyterLab instance with environment "TensorFlow:2.0"

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook, tensorboard, jupyter-lab

**In the instance with environment "TensorFlow:2.0":**
When using "Create new TensorBoard" function in JupyterLab, and Entering the path of log files that TensorFlow (No matter what version of TF we use, 1.12 to 2.0 tried) generated, Path window closes and no response.
Downgrading to lower versions (1.12 to 2.0) of TF doesn't help.

**However, TensorBoard can be opened every time in the instance with environment "TensorFlow:1.15".** No matter what version of TF (1.12 to 2.0) we actually installed in this instance.

Does the instance environment matter? What is the difference between the version numbers of **instance environment** and **TF we actually install**?